# Understanding how nth root can equal 1

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $ω = \cos(2π/n) + i \sin(2π/n)$ with $n$ a natural number. Show that
> $(1 − ω)(1 − ω^2)(1 − ω^3) ···(1 − ω^{n−1}) = n$.

The solution to this question states $ω^n = \cos(2π) + i \sin(2π) = 1$ and states the nth roots are all 1 which makes sense but then the equation becomes (0)(0)(0)...(0)=n which doesn't make sense since n is natural, in this case >1. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:In the process of reading comments, thanks to everyone who helped :D. Might take 15 minutes to read because im dyslexic.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please have a look at the mathjax basic tutorial for mathematical formatting: 
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does the solution actually say the nth roots are all 1, or does it perhaps say the nth roots are all roots of unity?

Answer (score 4):

You wish to prove
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-\omega^k)=n.$$

Since the $z=\omega^k$ (for $0\leq k<n$) are precisely the roots of $z^n-1$, we obtain
$$z^n-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z-\omega^k).$$

Dividing both sides by $z-1$ yields
$$z^{n-1}+\cdots +z+1=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(z-\omega^k).$$

Substituting $z=1$ gives the result.